# Crash debug iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsstring, crash-reports

I have a app in app store and there are reports of crashes, one of place from the logs points to the function below. Since I don't have the exact scenario to reproduce it what would be the best way to handle it. On testing even if I pass a `nil` to the `messageJSON` string it still doesn't crash. Any idea what could be causing the crash and how to handle it?

```
- (void)_dispatchMessage:(WVJBMessage*)message {
    NSString *messageJSON = [self _serializeMessage:message];
//Crash log points to this line below
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"]; 
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"\\\'"];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r"];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\f" withString:@"\\f"];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2028" withString:@"\\u2028"];
    messageJSON = [messageJSON stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2029" withString:@"\\u2029"];

    NSString* javascriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WebViewJavascriptBridge._handleMessageFromObjC('%@');", messageJSON];
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCommand];
    } else {
        __strong WVJB_WEBVIEW_TYPE* strongWebView = _webView;
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [strongWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCommand];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: It just says EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Comment: One issue could be that _serializeMessage is not returning NSString and hence you may be getting unrecognized selector crash. Without the crash log, it is difficult to ascertain something. You can use crashlytics(fabric) in your project for better logs.